# AWS S3Client PHP suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

today my web site which usually auto logs to aws s3 by php, can't connect anymore; the code hasn't changed at all.

```
 $s3Client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ],
    'http' => [
        'verify' => '../ssl_crt/cacert.pem'
    ]
]);
//echo var_dump($s3Client);

//Listing all S3 Bucket
$result = $s3Client->listBuckets();
```

the code above which has worked fine till yesterday now gets tomeout connection and therefore fails listing buckets.

I have read amazon has changed something in the permissions/policy, but I can't find how this can be related to PHP s3Client... maybe I could just change some setting in AWS S3 control panel, but I can't figure out what...Has anyone experienced the same issue

Comment: Any error message? In app or error log?

Comment: It auto-fixed as it auto-generated, no more errors.. Never changed a line on the site....